# PDF download corrupted / HTTP header problems

Tags: c++, pdf, http-headers, download

I have some legacy code in one of application which is used for PDF file download (PDF file is around 350-400KB size) and recently we had complains (from around 1% customers) saying PDF download is failing with damaged/corrupted file errors.

Here is snippet of code (C++ application) setting headers for download

```
String header;
header.append("Content-type: application/force-download\r\n");
header.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary\r\n");
header.append("Content-length: %d\r\n", filebuf.length());
header.append("Connection: Close\r\n");
header.append("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=%s\r\n\r\n", filename_to_download.chars());
```

String class and append method is just for an example.

I understand above headers are not the best way to trigger PDF file download (I've simplified headers by having "Content-Type application/octet-stream and Content-Disposition : attachment; filename=example.pdf" and seems like its working for me).

But I am not able to understand why above original code should not work 1% of time.

I was trying to understand browser/adobe combination but seems there is no pattern here, YES one thing few of customers mentioned is when they changed to "chrome browser" it worked most of the times.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of days of struggle finally figured out whats happening in here.

We are setting content length as size of buffer (pdf file size) in header from our code and sending this data to client but in-between apache module mod_gzip/mod_deflate is compressing data buffer and what reaches client/browser is "Content-Length: 100 bytes" but actual data is say 60-70 bytes.

Not every browser complains about this mismatch but certain browsers treats this as FATAL error and shows message "couldn't download file" (we've seen this issue frequently in Win8/IE10 and Win8/IE11, there could be some other security settings too causing this on browser!).

For the fix, we've removed "Content-Length" from header.